# Namespacing, OOP JS, Am I doing this right?

Tags: javascript, oop, namespaces

My problem is with objInfo(). How can I return an object via a passed-in variable? I'm trying to namespace my code and use private/public vars.

Bonus Q: How would you otherwise improve the code?

```
// Namespace all my code
var bab = new function() {

    // Declare cat object
    function cat()
    {
      this.eyes = 2;
      this.legs = 4;
      this.diet = 'carnivore';

      return true;
    }

    // Declare lion object
    function lion()
    {
      this.mane = true;
      this.origin = 'Africa';
      this.diet = 'people'; // has priority over cat's diet

      return true;
    }

    // Make lion a subclass of cat
    lion.prototype = new cat();

    // Create an instance of class lion
    var simba = new lion();

    // Share diet publicly
    this.objInfo = function(name) {
        return name; // simba works, name doesn't
    };

};

alert(bab.objInfo('simba').diet);
```

*Note: Source is sampled from various places*

Comment: I suggest to read some question and answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+namespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than namespacing, it's not clear to me what you're trying to do, but I've included a code review of sorts under the divider below. More high-level comments first.

There are a couple of issues here. First off, you almost *never* want to write `new function() { }`. It's a very advanced technique that's easy to get wrong (and very easy for anyone doing maintenance on the code to misunderstand). There's an example of another, less-confusing way to get the same effect (plus some other benefits) below.

Here's an example of a namespaced module providing two "classes", `Cat` and `Lion` (I've made them initially-capped because that's the usual convention: initial caps on constructor functions and initial lower case on non-constructor functions, just to make it easy to read code):

```
var Animals = (function() {
    var publics = {};

    // A Cat
    publics.Cat = Cat;
    function Cat() {
        this.eyes = 2;
        this.legs = 4;
        this.diet = 'carnivore';
    }

    // A Lion
    publics.Lion = Lion;
    function Lion() {
        this.mane = true;
        this.origin = 'Africa';
        this.diet = 'people'; // has priority over cat's diet
    }
    Lion.prototype = new Cat();

    // Return our public symbols
    return publics;
})();

// Usage
var l = new Animals.Lion();
alert(l.eyes); // alerts "2" (inherited from Cat)
alert(l.diet); // alerts "people" (overridden by Lion)
```

(You can, of course, call `publics` anything else you want — `pubs`, `p`, whatever. It's the equivalent of `this` in the outermost layer of your `new function() { }` function, but less confusing.)

But just replacing the prototype on `Lion` is a bit simplistic. When you start getting into subclassing, there are several other things you want to look at doing. [Here's a blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html) that details a fairly complete means of building classes, including subclassing, calling superclass functions, etc.

In terms of looking something up by string, you can do that with brackets notation on any object:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = 42;
alert(obj["foo"]); // alerts "42" by retrieving the property "foo" from `obj`
var x = "f" + "o" + "o";
alert(obj[x]);     // alerts "42" by retrieving the property "foo" from `obj`
```

Code review follows.

---

Here's a code review:

```
// Namespace all my code
// [TJC] Use the (function() { ... })(); mechanism described above rather than
// `new function() { ... }`, which is fairly confusing to the reader and troublesome
// to use inside inner functions (see below)
var bab = new function() {

    // Declare cat object
    // [TJC] Convention is to use initial caps for constructor functions,
    // e.g. "Cat" not "cat"
    function cat()
    {
      this.eyes = 2;
      this.legs = 4;
      this.diet = 'carnivore';

      // [TJC] Don't return anything out of constructor functions
      return true;
    }

    // Declare lion object
    // [TJC] "Lion" rather than "lion" would be more conventional
    function lion()
    {
      this.mane = true;
      this.origin = 'Africa';
      this.diet = 'people'; // has priority over cat's diet

      // [TJC] Don't return anything out of constructor functions
      return true;
    }

    // Make lion a subclass of cat
    // [TJC] There are several other things you want to consider in
    // addition to replacing the prototype
    lion.prototype = new cat();

    // Create an instance of class lion
    // [TJC] From your usage below, it looks like you
    // want to be able to look up "simba" using a string
    // later. So use the below rather than this commented-out
    // line:
    //var simba = new lion();
    var instances = {};           // [TJC]
    instances.simba = new lion(); // [TJC]

    // Share diet publicly
    // [TJC] You don't need a function for this at all, just
    // expose "instances" directly. But if you want it:
    this.objInfo = function(name) {
            // [TJC] To look up something by name using a string,
            // use brackets:
        //return name; // simba works, name doesn't
            return instances[name]; // [TJC]
    };

};

alert(bab.objInfo('simba').diet);
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough. But I'll try, Thanks*(1/0). Nope, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially made all but `objInfo()` in `bab` obsolete, since **`objInfo()` simply returns exactly what is passed into it.**

In your specific case, `objInfo("simba")` doesn't work since `objInfo()` simply returns the string `"simba"`:

```
    ...
    // Share diet publicly
    this.objInfo = function(name) { // <-- If name == "simba"
        return name; // <-- This will return "simba" not the Object simba!!!
    };

};

alert(bab.objInfo('simba').diet);​ // This will check for the diet property of
                                  //   the string "simba". So it won't work.
```

However there is a larger problem, as I mentioned before. **`objInfo()` simply returns exactly what is passed into it!**

Try out these examples:

```
alert(bab.objInfo('simba'));            // This will alert "simba"
alert(bab.objInfo('noodles'));          // This will alert "noodles"
alert(bab.objInfo(window).innerWidth);  // This will give you the innerWidth of
```

### **[jsFiddle example of `alert(bab.objInfo(window).innerWidth);`](http://jsfiddle.net/LHJe2/)**

You have essentially "short circuited" your entire `bab` object. Only the `objInfo` method "does" anything.

---

This is how I would do it:

```
// Namespace all my code
var bab = new function() {    
    var cat = function() // Declare cat object
    {
      var protected = {}; // Protected vars & methods
      protected.eyes = 2;
      protected.legs = 4;
      protected.diet = 'carnivore';
      return protected; // Pass protected to descendants
    }
    var lion = function()
    {     
      var protected = cat();  // Make lion a subclass of cat        
      var public = {}; // Public vars & methods
      public.legs = protected.legs; // Make 1 protected var public
      public.mane = true;
      public.origin = 'Africa';
      public.diet = 'people'; // has priority over cat's diet
      return public; // Make public vars available
    }    
    var simba = lion();     // Create an instance of class lion
    simba.diet = "Asparagus"; // Change simba, but not lion
    // Get property of choice
    this.objInfo = function(property) {
        return ("Simba: " + simba[property] +
                " - Lion (this is usually private. Shown for testing.): " +
                lion()[property]);
    };
};
alert(bab.objInfo("diet"));
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/uFFSe/)**

I used functional inheritance in the above. I find it simpler to work with and it makes good use of the classless nature of Javascript's Object Oriented persona.

As test output, I returned directly from `lion`... which you would not usually do, just to show that changing `Simba` doesn't change `lion`. You can tell that the `lion`'s diet has priority over the `cat`'s diet, just like you wanted.

The trick is to package your `protected` and `public` variables and methods in returned objects, and don't forget that you can also create methods in you felines.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval`, but I would hate to recommend that.

You might improve the script by "registering" your lions in an array.

```
// Namespace all my code
var bab = (function() {
        // Declare cat object
        function cat() {
            this.eyes = 2;
            this.legs = 4;
            this.diet = 'carnivore';

            return true;
        }

        // Declare lion object
        function lion() {
            this.mane = true;
            this.origin = 'Africa';
            this.diet = 'people'; // has priority over cat's diet

            return true;
        }

        // Make lion a subclass of cat
        lion.prototype = new cat();

        // Create an instance of class lion
//      var simba = new lion();
        var lions = {}; // Create a "lions" object to collect all of the lion instances
        lions["simba"] = new lion();

    return {
        // Share diet publicly
        objInfo: function(name) {
            return lions[name];
        };
    }
})();

alert(bab.objInfo('simba').diet);
```

I've edited the code to use a less error-prone form of encapsulation.  This article helped me a lot: [Public and Private in JavaScript](http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-private-public-privileged/).

Comment: Or go to the more definitive work by Crockford: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Yeah, that one, too, but that one is a bit more abstract.  The Dustin Diaz article introduced me to the concept to the point where I understood it, then the Crockford article completed my understanding.

Comment: Yeah, Crockford makes for dense reading. Would have been nice if Dustin Diaz had cited his sources, though, since he almost certainly read Crockford or someone who had read Crockford. :-)